# Can we have an integer polytope when $A$ is not totally unimodular and $b$ is an integer vector?

Tags: integer-programming, discrete-optimization, polytopes, unimodular-matrices

I am kind of confused. I know the theorem that: 
" Let $A$ be totally unimodular and b an integer vector. The
polytope
$P :$= {$x$ | $Ax$ ≤ $b$}
is integer (all vertices are integer)."

So I'm wondering if $A$ is a {$-1,0,1$} matrix and b is an integer vector  then the set {$Ax \leq b |$ R$^n$} is an integer polytope?

If this is true can you give me an example.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total unimodularity is a sufficient, but not necessary condition for a constraint matrix (given integral $b$) to define an integer polytope (cp. [Polyhedra with the Integer Carathéodory Property](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.4552.pdf)
). An example given by that paper:

\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1\\0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Why is it not unimodular? Like could you give the submatrix which has determinant not in {1,-1,0}